# Wrong type argument: stringp, ("~/capture.org")

Tags: debugging, find-file

I am setting up a few hydras, one of which should open a frequently accessed file. The following command works, if I bind a keyboard sequence to it:

```
(lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org"))
```

How would I rewrite it if I want to get the file (capture.org here) from a variable?

```
(setq my-file-variable "~/capture.org")
(lambda () (interactive) (find-file my-file-variable))
```

This returns an error: "Wrong type argument: stringp, ("~/capture.org")"

It seems that the variable contains a list with one element (the string I want), and not just the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you may have accidentally set `my-file-variable` to the list (such as with `(add-to-list 'my-file-variable "~/capture.org")` ?).  There's no stack trace, so I can't be absolutely certain, but something inside `find-file` is probably complaining that it has received a list argument rather than a string.

Just re-run your code exactly as you have it and it should work!

If it doesn't, try looking at the stack trace (and maybe update your question).  Use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to cause the function to break on the error in that case.

Comment: Of course. My bad. I c&p'ed code from org-ref that looked like this: `;; see org-ref for use of these variables
(setq org-ref-bibliography-notes "~/Dropbox/bibliography/notes.org"
      org-ref-default-bibliography '("~/Dropbox/bibliography/references.bib")
      org-ref-pdf-directory "~/Dropbox/bibliography/bibtex-pdfs/")`. And org-ref-default-bibliography was a list that I overlooked. Thanks!